# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e in interval function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the  following script that is runs after every three seconds :

```
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>cashier/regular_patient_payments",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (payment_list) {
                    pat_payment_list = $('#regular_patient_payment').empty();

                    $.each(payment_list, function (i, payment_list) {
                        pat_payment_list.append('<li><a href="#regular_patient_form" id="regular_payment_link" class="regular_payment_link"><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </i>\n\
                ' + payment_list.patient_name + '</a>\n\
      <input type="hidden" id="patient_id" name="patient_id" class="patient_id" value="' + payment_list.patient_id + '"/>\n\
<input type="hidden" id="visit_id" class="visit_id" name="visit_id" value="' + payment_list.visit_id + '" /></br></li>');


                    });



                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //error do something
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
```

But when the  script runs I get the following error :

> **TypeError**: invalid 'in' operand e
>   `...===n||"function"!==n&&(0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in e)}t=x(o),function...`

How can I solve the  above error ?

Comment: `payment_list` what type of response is it? post in the question too.

Comment: It returns an array of values

Comment: Is your script in a `.js` file or a `<script>` tag?